# Rotated labels figure fit on Bokeh

Tags: annotations, label, bokeh

A label gets fitted to figure (canvas) when placed by bokeh Label, but when it gets rotated that feature doesn't works.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Label, LabelSet, Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("label.html", title="label.py example")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(height=[66, 71, 72, 68, 58, 62],
                                    weight=[165, 189, 220, 141, 260, 174],
                                    names=['Mark', 'Amir', 'Matt', 'Greg',
                                           'Owen', 'Juan']))

p = figure(title='Dist. of 10th Grade Students at Lee High',
           x_range=Range1d(140, 275))
p.scatter(x='weight', y='height', size=8, source=source)
p.xaxis[0].axis_label = 'Weight (lbs)'
p.yaxis[0].axis_label = 'Height (in)'

# Fitted data
citation1 = Label(x=260, y=58, 
                 text='Fitted data even to figure', render_mode='css',
                 border_line_color='black', border_line_alpha=1.0,
                 background_fill_color='white', background_fill_alpha=1.0,
                 )

#Unfitted data
citation2 = Label(x=165, y=52, 
                 text='Unfitted data, get out of canvas', render_mode='canvas',
                 border_line_color='black', border_line_alpha=1.0,
                 background_fill_color='white', background_fill_alpha=1.0,
                 angle = 90, angle_units='deg')


p.add_layout(citation1)
p.add_layout(citation2)

show(p)
```

Any idea how to make a rotated label that can always be shown in a figure?

Comment: Your first label uses the CSS mode and not the canvas mode. Have you tried using CSS for the rotated version?

Comment: Yes the same, and something weird hapens to the coordinates due to the rotation